# Copying data from unbootable Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I have a Macbook unibody c. 2012 that will not boot (a coffee spill did it in).  I suspect the hard disk is ok and I would like to connect it to another machine to try to copy data off.  I'd like a "casual" interface, ala USB or firewire, as I may not have a similar laptop to use as a bootable host (I do have an older, non-unibody Macbook, however).

Is there some cabling I can procure that could allow me to do this?

tone

Comment: Do you want to pull the hard drive out of the machine? That would be the easiest way to do it. Then just get a SATA -> USB adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this iFixit guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Hard+Drive+Replacement/10378) -or the one for your specific MacBook, if this isn't- to remove the hard drive, but in short:

1. Remove the lower case
2. Disconnect the battery (with care, as you may break the connector)
3. Remove the hard drive

Then put your hard drive on a [USB 3 case](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Anker%C2%AE-Drive-External-Enclosure-9-5mm/dp/B00H98AXOE) and you're ready to plug it to any Mac or HFS capable Windows or Linux machine to recover your data.